# How do I focus a button inside modal when the modal is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

When call modal popup I need to focus on the first button on the modal.
The button is dynamically appended to the modal footer

```
var difVal = ( totalAmnt - payAble ).toFixed(2);         
$('#chqMsgContent').html( 'Total Diffrent than the Recive Amount. ( ' + difVal + ' )</br> (Please type manually for over payment) ');        
$('#myModal').modal('show');
$('.modal-dialog').css('width', '350');     
var btnsForModl = '<input type="button" class="btn  btn-xs ok" id="okDif" data-dismiss="modal" value="Ok" data-value="Cash" /> ';       
$('.modal-footer').html(btnsForModl);   

$('#okDif').focus();
```

`$('#okDif').focus();` not worked than I have tried this on

```
$('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
     alert($('#okDif').val());
     $('#okDif').focus();
});
```

Both of the methods are not working, but the popup window is working fine.

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nsk21/DTcHh/12012/)

Comment: can you post a fiddle jsfiddle.net?

Comment: there is a big process to get the pop up in my system is it possible to post the complete page on jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nsk21/DTcHh/12012/

Comment: Ok this has me stumped. There something weird going on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything inside the modal is initially *hidden*, therefore the `input` element (as *hidden*) cannot have *focus* on. 
If you don't need the modal to be animated, you could simply remove the `fade` class of the modal, so that the modal content is visible right away after you call `.modal('show')`.
[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/z92dekq7/)

---

The other option which you have tried won't work because bootstrap *modal* has no event called `shown`.
It has a [**`shown.bs.modal`**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) event:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e){
    $('#okDif').focus();
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/x9sLvn6g/)

Comment: it is work now just after removing the **fade** like you said thank you.. and the `$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e){` function is no need

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a slight timeout for the focus command, as otherwise it fires before the element is present.

This works:

```
$(document).on('click', '#on', function(){  
  $('#chqMsgContent').html('Total Diffrent than the Recive Amount');         
  ...
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    $("#okDif").focus();
  }, 150);
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/ofe7y1hc/)**

Comment: when the popup is appear that focus on the button with in a second focus disappear .. how ever  after removing the **fade**  class your code is working ... thank you for your answer

Comment: A one second timeout worked for me James. Thanks for the tip.